# I have three forms on the same page and I want to use jQuery to validate them separately

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am still new to jQuery and trying to set up validation for three separate forms on one page. The forms are quite simple, the first is only a text input and submit, the second two just a single select elements and submit. I want each submit to be be disabled until its corresponding element has content.

What I have managed so far is to is to disable all the submits until all elements have content.

What I need to do is rewrite so it is specific each form.

http://codepen.io/drgs100/pen/tJCzv

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, or what isn't currently working. Can you be more clear? What do you mean "select one form at a time"?

Comment: HI Jon, I have rewritten, hopefully with more clarity. Cheers.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to leave an answer, but I think this is kind of what you're looking for: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zyipu

Comment: Bang on, thanks for your help. You can't leave an answer because I went off topic (or asked a bad question and showed poor knowledge).

Comment: For the moderators: this question has been updated to be on-topic and I've got a solution to submit. Any chance you could remove the "on hold"?

Comment: I've updated my answer, check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, lets figure you want to achieve something like the following:

```
$('form').each(function(){
     $(this).submit();
})
```

UPDATE:

Sorry I didn't see your modification, I have figured something like the following, I think it could be better coded though a little hint for you.

```
$("input[type=text], select").keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val() != ''){
        $(this).next().attr("disabled", false);
  }else{
    $(this).next().attr("disabled", true);
  }
}).change(function(){
  if($(this).val() != ''){
        $(this).next().attr("disabled", false);
  }else{
    $(this).next().attr("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

That makes more sense to you?

UPDATE 2:

Based on @Jon comment here is a better function for OP question, as nobody would be able to answer why not to help out others handling the same situation:

```
var submits = $("form .submit");

function containBlanks (elem) {
  return $(elem).siblings(".required").val() === "";
}

function requiredFilledIn(elems){
  elems.each(function() {
    if (containBlanks(this)) {
      $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
      $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
    }
  });
}

requiredFilledIn(submits);

$("form span").hide();

$("input[type=text], select").focus(function(){
        $(this).next().next().fadeIn("slow");
  }).blur(function(){
        $(this).next().next().fadeOut("slow");
  }).keyup(function(){
        requiredFilledIn($(this).siblings("input[type=submit]"));
}).change(function(){
        requiredFilledIn($(this).siblings("input[type=submit]"));
});
```

Credit for @Jon

Comment: Thanks. I think that is what I was looking for, will try tomorrow. Have rewritten in an attempt to be clearer.

Comment: Given the updated question, that's not a viable solution

Comment: @Jon As the question is closed I updated my answer in your credit.. :)